# undefined reference to duckx

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Пытаюсь добавить в проект библиотеку https://github.com/AlexanderVatov/DuckX. С использованием qmake.

Столкнулся с следующими ошибками при выполнении тестового кода, предложенного автором библиотеки:

[image: ошибки]

.pro файл выглядит следующим образом:

[image: .pro]

Для решения проблемы пробовал пересобрать проект.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Проблема была в компиляторе. Для компиляции библиотеки я использовал  Microsoft compiler а для, компиляции проекта MinGW. Поменял MinGW на Microsoft compiler и все заработало.